# Are there an easy way to coloring tables depending on the value in each cell?

Tags: tables, color

I viewed in this post [Conditional format for correlation table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126959/conditional-format-for-correlation-table) a solution to my question, but...

[image]

Are there any easier way (or alternative) to do this using colors?

Thank you.
------------------ edited after showed than it´s duplicate -------------
I think that there are many sols, but for example this is easy using a normal table without pgf...

[the Unas answer is interesting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz)

I´m trying to adapt to similar colors to apply to the table probabilitiess

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174234/47522

Comment: There are several other answers that accomplish this with different twists. The one you mention in your OP seems good also. You might try extending that by using a color mix model like
`colora!<number>!colorb`. Where *number * is between 0-100 and represents the percent mixture of the colors.

Comment: Doing this kind of stuff is a total pain in the arse in Latex IMO.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton What´s "IMO" ?  Is "arse" a bad-sound word?. I can´t still view an answer using colors to make a Temperature Map. All it´s Blank/White

Comment: In my opinion...

Comment: @MikaIke: IMO: In my opinion ;-) .. i.e. in Nicholas opinion, to be precise ;-)

Comment: I needed to do this once, I found that the best way was to use 'collectcell' as described here: http://texblog.org/2013/06/13/latex-heatmap-using-tabular/

Comment: @MikaIke: have a look to [Drawing heatmaps using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83865/13304) then.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton Thank You, I´m seeing this Unla´s answer because It´s simply and You can use normal Tables.  I´m trying to obtains similar colors to the image. gradual Green background to >0.5 and red for <0.5 as much red as close to 0, and as more green as close to 1. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/parametrize-shading-in-table-through-tikz I´m not sure to reach the solutions I want :-)

Comment: Like I said. Its a pain compared to what you are used to.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton It only takes a very minimal amount of markup, not sure what you think is a "pain" ? (see posted answer)

Comment: I dont see that as an answer, since it only offers three colours, my understanding of the question was that Mika wanted a gradient depending on value.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton Yes, you´re right

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Adapted from the link that I mentioned in my comments to the question (ie click [HERE](http://texblog.org/2013/06/13/latex-heatmap-using-tabular/)), here is a solution which produces the following:

[image]

A subtle difference between this solution, and the base code taken from the above link, is that this solution introduces max, min and MIDPOINT values, so that one gradient is achieved for the lower half (yellow -> red), and another for the upper half (yellow -> green) of the numbers.

I have also added a max / min limit to the calculated values, so that they are in the range 0 to 100, if they are outside this value, errors are thrown.

Here is the code to do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

 %The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.5} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \fi
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{*{10}{R}}
              1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.37 \\
              1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.01 \\
              1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.00 \\
              1.00 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\
              0.99 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.98 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.95 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.90 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.82 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.37 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For the record, I find it totally frustrating producing things like the following, where NOT ALL of the cells are subject to the shading, and, there are header rows etc. I am sure there is a more glamorous way to do this, and I am interested in finding out how...

[image]

Comment: Yes :-) Thank You very much, It´s the solution. Now for particular tastes you can set green and red, less or mor brigthness but...  This message is THE SOLUTION :-) I think that this code with a row and a col for the labels... may be a good solution to other users. For me it´s valid so.

Comment: Thanks. But for the record, I find it entirely frustrating working with tables in latex for anything over and above the usual B&W varieties. I have modified my answer to show what can be done based on some of my work, but it is very painful in my opinion...

Comment: Yes, now I understand when you said "PAIN" :-) Yes, but it´s not onl with table that it´s a PAIN ;-) There many things. The results are pretty, but.. the effort is high. Sometimes I think that Latex is close to a 
punishment that I have chosed for my final job.

Comment: I don't think so, just tables are my personal gripe. Everything else is awesome.

Comment: \nicholas-hamilton I´m starting using psmatrix and flowcharts (and similar with otherr packages and things), and any little thing you want to add, you need to use other package, or there are any special variable to define or anything... It´s pretty but.. sometimes it´s so complicated, and a little change... generates multiple complications. Are there any post/posts where to learn good practices?

Comment: David Carlisle would know, sorry, but I don't purport to be an expert ...

Comment: Hi what if the number is very large? Say 100999

Answer (score 17):

[image]

The linked questions give answers if you are using pgfplotstable/tikz but they are not needed if you only want colouring and not the other features of those packages. The following aligns the numbers on the comma and gives one of three background colours depending on the value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl,dcolumn}

\def\zz#1{%
\ifdim#1pt<5pt\cellcolor{green}\else
\ifdim#1pt<50pt\cellcolor{yellow}\else
\cellcolor{red}\fi\fi
#1}


\begin{document}



\begin{tabular}{*3{D,,{2.2}}c}
\zz {1,2} &\zz  {3,04}  &\zz {5,44}  \\
\zz {1,01}&\zz {77,5}  &\zz {77,94} \\
\zz {3,42}&\zz   {4,04} &\zz {51,04} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It´s not exactly a temperature using the gradient to show how close or far are to the max /min but, I like your code. It´s possible I use it in other cases. Thank you.

Comment: @MikaIke no I just use \ifdim to split it into three ranges but obviously you can put any test you want there

Answer (score 4):

The solution by Nicholas Hamilton does not work if you want to have non-numeric header in the table.  I have found the following workaround (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40603):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40603 - only color in table body
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{inTableHeader}% Track if still in header of table
\toggletrue{inTableHeader}% Set initial value
\newcommand*{\StartTableHeader}{\global\toggletrue{inTableHeader}}%
\newcommand*{\EndTableHeader}{\global\togglefalse{inTableHeader}}%

% Redefine tabular to initialize \StartTableHeader at start and end
\let\OldTabular\tabular%
\let\OldEndTabular\endtabular%
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\StartTableHeader\OldTabular}{\OldEndTabular\StartTableHeader}%

 %The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.5} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{
    \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
        \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
    \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
        \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
    \fi
  }}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{*{10}{R}}
              A    & B    & C    & D    & E    & F    & G    & H    & I    & J    \EndTableHeader\\
              \hline
              1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.37 \\
              1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.01 \\
              1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.00 \\
              1.00 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\
              0.99 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.98 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.95 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.90 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.82 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.37 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: The resulting table]

Answer (score 4):

An interesting solution was posted [on this blog post](https://www.siavoosh.com/blog/2019/01/05/latex-table-cell-coloring-based-on-values-in-the-cell/#respond):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Based on https://www.siavoosh.com/blog/2019/01/05/latex-table-cell-coloring-based-on-values-in-the-cell/#respond
%======================================
% Packages
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf} % for calculating the values for gradient
%======================================
% Color set related!
\definecolor{high}{HTML}{76f013}  % the color for the highest number in your data set
\definecolor{low}{HTML}{ec462e}  % the color for the lowest number in your data set
\newcommand*{\opacity}{90}% here you can change the opacity of the background color!
%======================================
% Data set related!
\newcommand*{\minval}{0.0}% define the minimum value on your data set
\newcommand*{\maxval}{1.0}% define the maximum value in your data set!
%======================================
% gradient function!
\newcommand{\gradient}[1]{
    % The values are calculated linearly between \minval and \maxval
    \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{\maxval pt}{#1}{
        \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{<}{\minval pt}{#1}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(100*(#1/(\maxval-\minval))-(\minval*(100/(\maxval-\minval)))))}
            \xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}
            \cellcolor{high!\tempa!low!\opacity} #1
    }}
}
%======================================
% gradient function single cell! 
\newcommand{\gradientcell}[6]{
    % The values are calculated linearly between \minval and \maxval
    \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{#3 pt}{#1}{
        \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{<}{#2 pt}{#1}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(100*(#1/(#3-#2))-(\minval*(100/(#3-#2)))))}
            \xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}
            \cellcolor{#5!\tempa!#4!#6} #1
    }}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
              \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{0.99} & \gradient{0.98} & \gradient{0.96} & \gradient{0.90} & \gradient{0.82} & \gradient{0.37} \\
              \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{0.99} & \gradient{0.98} & \gradient{0.95} & \gradient{0.90} & \gradient{0.82} & \gradient{0.61} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.01} \\
              \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{0.99} & \gradient{0.98} & \gradient{0.96} & \gradient{0.90} & \gradient{0.82} & \gradient{0.67} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.14} & \gradient{0.00} \\
              \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{0.98} & \gradient{0.95} & \gradient{0.90} & \gradient{0.78} & \gradient{0.61} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.08} & \gradient{0.01} & \gradient{0.00} \\
              \gradient{0.99} & \gradient{0.95} & \gradient{0.90} & \gradient{0.82} & \gradient{0.61} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.14} & \gradient{0.01} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} \\
              \gradient{0.98} & \gradient{0.90} & \gradient{0.82} & \gradient{0.67} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.14} & \gradient{0.02} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} \\
              \gradient{0.95} & \gradient{0.78} & \gradient{0.61} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.08} & \gradient{0.01} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} \\
              \gradient{0.90} & \gradient{0.61} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.14} & \gradient{0.01} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} \\
              \gradient{0.82} & \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.14} & \gradient{0.02} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} \\
              \gradient{0.37} & \gradient{0.01} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

As the author notes, this solution does not require to affect an entire column, and there is a `\gradientcell{cell_val}{min_val}{max_val}{colorlow}{colorhigh}{opacity}` command if you want to tweak only some isolated cells:

```
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
    \hhline{~*{6}{-}} % Requires the package hhline.
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
    \gradient{10} & \gradient{0.01} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.50} & \gradient{1.00}\\
    11 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\gradientcell{75}{1}{100}{green}{blue}{30}}\\\hline
    12 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\gradientcell{90}{1}{100}{green}{blue}{30} You can even have text!}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Hi, what if the number is very large, for example, 89090?

Comment: You can accommodate any data set / values, just change the range for `minval` and `maxval` (0.0 and 1.0 by default) in the `\newcommand*{\minval}{0.0}% define the minimum value on your data set
\newcommand*{\maxval}{1.0}% define the maximum value in your data set!` commands.

Comment: Hey, my table used to display all values nicely, since I added your gradient command, all the cells with a 3 digit number break (the cell becomes two lines high, even though all 3 digits are in the first line). Any idea?

Comment: @felixmp I tested briefly and was not able to reproduce your behavior. Please, consider opening a new question and providing a MWE, and I can investigate for you. Comment here so that I'll see your question.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly. I fixed the error by changing p{0,6cm} to wc{2.5em} with the array package and \setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}. No idea what caused it, but it works now.

Comment: @felixmp I'm glad you were able to solve your problem. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: Is it possible to prevent `\gradient` from widening the cell?

Comment: @elya5 I'm not sure. Could you please open a separate question, link it from here, and provide a minimal example?

Comment: Is it possible to make the colors row-dependent in case we report values based on different scales?

Comment: @JamesArten Possibly, using a version of `\gradient` that takes as arguments the colors, maybe? Please, open another question and describe your problem precisely, with a minimal working example.

Comment: thanks @Clément, you can find my question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701406/obtaining-a-heatmap-with-row-wise-scale-in-a-latex-table?noredirect=1#comment1744133_701406

Answer (score 1):

Building off of earlier answers, to ignore any field that does not contain a decimal number, you can use `xstring`'s `\IfDecimal{}{}{}` macro, for example:

```
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \IfDecimal{#1}{
        \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)}
            \edef\x{ \noexpand\cellcolor{green!\PercentColor!yellow} }
            \x #1
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)}
            \edef\x{ \noexpand\cellcolor{red!\PercentColor!yellow} }
            \x #1
        \fi
    }{#1}
}
```