# \ifdim with argument < 1pt?

Tags: tables

I am trying to implement a kind-of-conditional coloring for a table based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175035/233834) (the preferable ones above in this thread don't work out as my number format is german so I have commas as decimal separators); however, there is another (presumably small) issue with this suggestion: My numbers which I like to have colored range from 0.01 to approx. 1.
However, if I replace the

```
\ifdim#1pt<5pt\cellcolor{green}
```

with smaller numbers (e.g. 0.1pt), there is an error stating
"Illegal parameter number in definition of zz".

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: MWE resulting in 55 errors, the only difference from the original code I got from the answer is that I changed 1pt to .1pt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl,dcolumn}

\def\zz#1{%
\ifdim#0.1pt<5pt\cellcolor{green}\else
\ifdim#1pt<50pt\cellcolor{yellow}\else
\cellcolor{red}\fi\fi
#1}


\begin{document}



\begin{tabular}{*3{D,,{2.2}}c}
\zz {0,2} &\zz  {3,04}  &\zz {5,44}  \\
\zz {1,01}&\zz {77,5}  &\zz {77,94} \\
\zz {3,42}&\zz   {4,04} &\zz {51,04} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Removing the # before the 0.1pt resolves the error, however then it just doesn't work as intended.

Comment: there is no error from `\ifdim0.001pt<5pt yes \else no\fi`  If you want help with an error please supply a small complete test file that makes the error then people can debug it for you

Comment: the error message you quote is unrelated to code shown and means you have `\newcommand\zz[1]{...#2}` with a definition with1 declared argument where you try to use a second argument.

Comment: thanks for your fast replies! I added an MWE showing the error(s).

Comment: `\ifdim#1pt` is not `#` followed by `1pt` but it means `#1` (the first parameter) followed by `pt`, so `\ifdim#0.1pt` is wrong. However, I'm not sure what your are trying to do.

Comment: Can you please state what comparisons you're trying to do? Not in TeX language, but in plain words.

Comment: Your input to `\zz` is a pair of numbers.  What do they both represent?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes forget brexit: that is a single number with a decimal comma

Comment: ohhhh thanks @campa I interpreted the #1pt<... as a range in between which the color is set as desired. Now if i knew how to set this as "answered" i'd be even happier.

Comment: @egreg I was trying to compare the number in the field to (several) intervals where each interval leads to a different coloring of the field.

Comment: @Sempft That's clear, but *what* comparisons are you doing?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the clarification for us rebels across the pond.

Comment: @egreg I was trying to compare the number in the table to several intervals to determine the color of the field. I misunderstood the #1pt<5pt as the interval and did not understand that #1 is the argument which is passed to the comparison. Now I got it, the problem is solved and I do not find the "solved"-button :(

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the term #1pt<5pt as the interval, while #1 corresponds to the number which is passed to the comparison. Therefore

```
\def\zz#1{%
\ifdim#1pt<0.1pt\cellcolor{green}\else
\ifdim#1pt<0.5pt\cellcolor{yellow}\else
\cellcolor{red}\fi\fi
#1}
```

works as intended. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The following adds two new column types called `\sempftcolored` and `\SempftColored`. With those you can set an alignment and colour your cells according to some colour ranges you can either specify with `\sempftsetcolors` or in the first and second argument of `\SempftColored`.

It uses a loop to find the correct cell colour. The list of colour specifications being used in the first argument of `\sempftsetcolors` or `\SempftColored` should have a comma separated list, each containing of two groups, the first being a relation (e.g., `{<0.1}` for smaller than 0.1) and the second the colour specification which should be applied. The second argument of `\sempftsetcolors` and `\SempftColored` is the colour which is applied if none of the relations matched.

For the relations you can use `=`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=` (and theoretically a few more which you will not need). The first matched relation is used (so order in `\sempftsetcolors` matters).

The argument of `\sempftcolored` and the last argument of `\SempftColored` are the cell alignments which should be applied.

`\sempftcellcolor` (the macro used to evaluate the relations and sets the cellcolor) works with both `,` (a comma) and `.` (a period) as the decimal separator of the argument (the cell content in a `\sempftcolored` column), whereas the numbers used in the colour lists must use a period.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % just for more named colours
\usepackage{dcolumn,collcell,array}

%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with newer LaTeX versions

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_sempft_color_ranges_seq
\tl_new:N \l_sempft_color_else_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \sempftsetcolors { m m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_sempft_color_ranges_seq {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_sempft_color_else_tl {#2}
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \sempftcellcolor { m }
  {
    \sempft_color_loop:e { \sempft_ensure_decimal_period:n {#1} }
    #1
  }
\cs_new:Npn \sempft_color_loop:n #1
  {
    \seq_map_tokens:Nn \l_sempft_color_ranges_seq
      { \__sempft_color_loop:nn {#1} }
    \use:n { \cellcolor { \l_sempft_color_else_tl } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sempft_color_loop:n { e }
\cs_new:Npn \__sempft_color_loop:nn #1#2
  {
    \__sempft_color_loop:nnn {#1} #2
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__sempft_color_loop:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \fp_compare:nT { #1 #2 }
      { 
        \cellcolor {#3}
        \seq_map_break:n { \use_none:nn }
      }
  }
% auxiliary function to parse floats correctly regardless of the decimal
% separator being a period or comma
\cs_new:Npn \sempft_ensure_decimal_period:n #1
  { \__sempft_ensure_decimal_period_auxi:w \q_nil #1 \q_mark , \q_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__sempft_ensure_decimal_period_auxi:w #1 ,
  { \__sempft_ensure_decimal_period_auxii:w #1 .  }
\cs_new:Npn \__sempft_ensure_decimal_period_auxii:w #1 \q_mark #2 \q_stop
  { \exp_not:o { \use_none:n #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\sempftsetcolors{{<0.1}{green}, {<0.5}{yellow}, {<1}{orange}}{red}

\newcolumntype\sempftcolored[1]
  {>{\collectcell\sempftcellcolor}#1<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype\SempftColored[3]
  {>{\sempftsetcolors{#1}{#2}\collectcell\sempftcellcolor}#3<{\endcollectcell}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
  {
    \sempftcolored{D,,{1.2}}
    \SempftColored{{<10}{green},{<20}{orange}}{red}{D,,{2.1}}
  }
  0,44 &  5,2 \\
  0,94 & 15,3 \\
  0,04 & 20,4 \\
  1,45 & 30,5 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]