# Gradient coloring of table with header different from column type

Tags: tables, color

I adopted this code from [Are there an easy way to coloring tables depending on the value in each cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174998/are-there-an-easy-way-to-coloring-tables-depending-on-the-value-in-each-cell) . It works over Overleaf but with one error, yet it produces the desired output. However, the same code doesn't run on Texmaker 5.0.4 due to the error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
p
l.62 \end{tabularx}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
```

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\newtoggle{inTableHeader}%
\toggletrue{inTableHeader}%
\newcommand*{\StartTableHeader}{\global\toggletrue{inTableHeader}}%
\newcommand*{\EndTableHeader}{\global\togglefalse{inTableHeader}}%

\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{10}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{25}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{50}%
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{
    \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
        \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
    \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
        \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{white!\PercentColor!gray}{#1}
    
    \fi
  }}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\rot}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\adjustbox{angle=90,lap=\width-1em}{#1}}}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Product groups interaction}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.18\textwidth}*{11}{R}}  \hline
&
\rot{ Animal} &
\rot{ Vegetables } &
\rot{ Food} &
\rot{ Minerals} &
\rot{ Footwear} &
\rot{ Fuel} &
\rot { Chemicals} &
\rot{ Plastic} &
\rot{ Leather} &
\rot{ Wood } &
\rot{ Textile} \EndTableHeader \\ \hline
Animal  &      & 28.2 & 13.5 & 9.91  & 10.3 & 16.5 & 9.01  & 15.0 & 11.3 & 9.03  & 9.02  \\
Vegetables   & 14.6 &     & 23.0 & 15.8 & 15.0 & 23.3 & 27.0 & 34.7 & 18.3 & 7.71  & 10.3 \\
Food        & 40.6 & 58.5 &    & 51.9 & 64.6 & 55.5 & 47.0 & 48.1 & 49.8 & 56.8 & 54.8 \\
Minerals      & 30.3 & 29.3 & 35.8 &    & 33.9 & 34.1 & 25.9 & 34.1 & 33.5 & 26.7 & 29.9 \\
Footwear   & 17.7 & 19.6 & 32.9 & 24.4 &    & 27.2 & 23.6 & 43.3 & 30.1 & 15.5 & 23.2 \\
Fuel   & 24.7 & 39.0 & 36.2 & 28.3 & 26.9 &     & 26.4 & 24.8 & 24.0 & 20.9 & 24.4 \\
Chemicals     & 11.5 & 12.7 & 33.3 & 16.1 & 11.7 & 20.0 &    & 23.7 & 16.6 & 6.72  & 10.2 \\
Plastic     & 25.3 & 24.6 & 19.7 & 24.6 & 22.7 & 27.6 & 17.3 &    & 28.6 & 19.9 & 20.3 \\
Leather   & 15.1 & 29.7 & 21.1 & 15.0 & 14.4 & 16.3 & 9.02  & 15.5 &     & 10.5 & 10.8 \\
Wood & 16.7 & 7.83  & 18.9 & 15.9 & 8.74  & 13.9 & 28.8 & 15.2 & 19.8 &    & 7.31  \\
Textile   & 20.0 & 31.3 & 33.4 & 22.1 & 20.0 & 31.6 & 32.4 & 32.7 & 28.1 & 14.3 &   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message is coming from the code `\ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt`.  When `#1` (the cell contents) is blank, this expands to `\ifdim pt > ...` which is missing a number before the `p`.

Your table has blank cells, which is what's causing the problem.

Here's a patched definition of `\ApplyGradient` that does nothing within blank cells:

```latex
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{inTableHeader}{#1}{%
    \def\NumberArgument{#1}%
    \ifx\NumberArgument\empty\else
      \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)}%
          \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}%
      \else
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)}%
          \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{white!\PercentColor!gray}{#1}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }}
```

Comment: Hello @edemaine, Thanks for your suggestion. The code does run but is doing a strange thing: the number like 11, 22, 33 are disappearing before the decennial point!

Comment: or the best can be done if the empty cells are left white and color only other cells

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in my code.  I updated the code and it seems to work!