# Provide value-dependent color to \cellcolor command

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I would like to create a table-based heatmap. The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175035/70170 looks like what I need, but instead of three fixed colors, I'd like to call `\cellcolor{}` with a color dependent on the cell value.

Here's my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{6}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{8} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{14}%

\def\zz#1{%
  \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
     \pgfmathparse{int(100*((#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber)))} %
     \cellcolor{yellow!\pgfmathresult!red} 
  \else
     \pgfmathparse{int(100*((\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber)))} %
     \cellcolor{green!\pgfmathresult!yellow} 
  \fi
#1}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \zz{6}  & \zz{7}  & \zz{8}  \\
  \zz{9}  & \zz{10} & \zz{11} \\
  \zz{12} & \zz{13} & \zz{14}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this does not produce the expected gradient result, but only pure yellow or pure red cells. I printed the `\pgfmathresult` to check that the computation is correct, and also tried some hardcoded offset like `yellow!20!red`, which works as well.

I must be overlooking the obvious, but can't figure out what it is. Help from the TeX expert would be much appreciated - thank you!

Note that I am not looking for alternative approaches to creating heatmap tables, but for a way to fix the approach using `\colortbl`'s `\cellcolor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\cellcolor` should be (after expansion) the first item in the cell, with no unexpandable token before it.

You can use `\fpeval`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpcompareTF}{mmm}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{6}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{8} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{14}%

\newcommand{\zz}[1]{%
  \fpcompareTF{#1>\MidNumber}{%
    \cellcolor{%
      yellow!\fpeval{round(100*((#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber)),0)}!red%
    }%
  }{%
    \cellcolor{%
      green!\fpeval{round(100*((\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber)),0)}!yellow%
    }%
  }%
  #1%
}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \zz{6}  & \zz{7}  & \zz{8}  \\
  \zz{9}  & \zz{10} & \zz{11} \\
  \zz{12} & \zz{13} & \zz{14}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg for this lightning fast and very helpful answer!