# Using cellcolor in new command changes cell width

Tags: tables, cellcolor

I have used the latex command presented [in this TexStackExchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174998/are-there-an-easy-way-to-coloring-tables-depending-on-the-value-in-each-cell/642581#642581) to create a table with cell background color based on the cell's numerical value.

The code works but it is changing the cell width. While the newly defined command uses `\cellcolor`, the same behavior does not occur when using `\cellcolor` directly.

Here is an example document which illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{hhline} % used for the top-most horizontal line! in order to fix the top left corner cell empty
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf} % for calculating the values for gradient
%======================================
% Color set related!
\definecolor{high}{HTML}{0083b6}  % the color for the highest number in your data set
\definecolor{low}{HTML}{ffffff}  % the color for the lowest number in your data set
\newcommand*{\opacity}{70}% here you can change the opacity of the background color!
%======================================
% Data set related!
\newcommand*{\minval}{0.0}% define the minimum value on your data set
\newcommand*{\maxval}{1.0}% define the maximum value in your data set!
%======================================
% gradient function!
\newcommand{\gradient}[1]{
    % The values are calculated linearly between \minval and \maxval
    \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{>}{\maxval pt}{#1}{
        \ifdimcomp{#1pt}{<}{\minval pt}{#1}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(round(100*(#1/(\maxval-\minval))-(\minval*(100/(\maxval-\minval)))))}
            \xdef\tempa{\pgfmathresult}
            \cellcolor{high!\tempa!low!\opacity} #1
    }}
}


\renewcommand{\opacity}{50}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Version A}
    \label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
        \hhline{~*{3}{-}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & A & B & C \\ \hline
        1 & \gradient{0.20} & \gradient{0.00} & \cellcolor{red}{0.00}  \\ \hline
        6 & \gradient{0.80} & \gradient{1.00} & \cellcolor{red}{0.00}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Version B}
    \label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
        \hhline{~*{3}{-}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & A & B & C \\ \hline
        1 & \gradient{0.20} & \gradient{0.00} & \gradient{0.00}  \\ \hline
        6 & \gradient{0.80} & \gradient{1.00} & \gradient{0.00}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to keep the same cell width?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would guess that this is due to the spaces which are added to the cell because of the uncommented line breaks in the defintion of `\gradient`. Make sure to end every line in the defintion with a `%` and/or remove empty lines from the code of the defintion.

Comment: You mean the two empty lines? They don't have an impact. I updated the example accordingly.

Comment: Jasper is correct you have sporadic spaces at the end of the lines in your definition of `\gradient` end each line with `%` to remove them. I added 7 (probably not all needed) to your example and the two tables have the same width (if you also remove the space before `#1` on the `\cellcolor` line).

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the returning value of the `\gradient` command does not contain any spurious spaces. Line breaks and empty lines will result in such spaces. Also, you could do without the help of `etoolbox` since PGF already provides its own if-then syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}

\definecolor{high}{HTML}{0083b6}  
\definecolor{low}{HTML}{ffffff} 
\newcommand*{\opacity}{70}
\newcommand*{\minval}{0.0}
\newcommand*{\maxval}{1.0}

\newcommand{\gradient}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        #1 > \maxval ? 100 : ( #1 < \minval ? 0 : 
            int( round(
                100 * ( #1 / ( \maxval - \minval) ) -
                ( \minval * ( 100 / ( \maxval - \minval ) ) )
            ) )
        )
    }%
    \xdef\colorval{\pgfmathresult}%
    \cellcolor{high!\colorval!low!\opacity}#1%
}

\renewcommand{\opacity}{50}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Version A}
    \label{tab:mytab}
    \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
        \hhline{~*{3}{-}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & A & B & C \\ \hline
        1 & \gradient{0.20} & \gradient{0.00} & \cellcolor{red}{0.00}  \\ \hline
        6 & \gradient{0.80} & \gradient{1.00} & \cellcolor{red}{0.00}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]